# Creating new row based on condition from 2 columns and filling field in table with 0 value (SQL/Access)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two tables: First Table *LocationsOFproducts* - Keep data about location of products and quantity, second table *Datahistory* keep data about stock movement ( removing/adding product from/to stock ).
I have two Queries:  First *SumDataHistoryQuery* - Making Sum of Products moved from the same location (from *Datahistory table*) ,Second *TOTAL QTY* - Counting how many products left in some location after stock movement.
In the *TOTAL QTY* Query I have also function ,Nz(SumDatahistoryQuery.SumOfQTY,0) to fill with 0 all Products in some locations without quantity taken from *Datahistory table*.

SQL Code:

```
SELECT LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no], LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code], LocationsOFproducts.LocationQTY, Nz([SumDatahistoryQuery].[SumOfQTY],0) AS SumOfQTY, ([LocationQTY])+([SumOfQTY]) AS TOTALQTY
FROM LocationsOFproducts 
LEFT JOIN SumDatahistoryQuery ON (LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code] = SumDatahistoryQuery.[Product Code]) 
AND (LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no] = SumDatahistoryQuery.[Bay no]) 
AND (LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code] = SumDatahistoryQuery.[Product Code])
GROUP BY LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no], LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code], LocationsOFproducts.LocationQTY, Nz([SumDatahistoryQuery].[SumOfQTY],0), ([LocationQTY])+([SumOfQTY])
ORDER BY LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code];
```

My problem is when user typing product code and location with quantity in *Datahistory* table and that product didn't exist in that location (in *LocationOFproducts* table) my query didn't count it.
I think in that case that Query should check is that product exist in that location? - if not it should add product code,location and 0 value to new row in *LocationsOfproducts* table and make a sum of values from those two tables.
I know that I should use "CASE WHEN, IF NOT EXISTS and INSERT INTO" functions but I don't have idea how to implement them into that Query which I have.
Did anyone know how to change this query to do what I want?
Thanks in advance!

I tried to write first query as Minty sugested but it didn't work.

`SELECT Datahistory.[Product Code], Datahistory.[Bay no] , Datahistory.QTY , CASE WHEN LocationsOFproducts.[Bay no] =! 1.[Bay no] AND LocationsOFproducts.[Product Code] =! 1.[Product Code] FROM Datahistory 1`

It showing Syntax error (misssing operator)

Answer (score 0):

You would need two queries to achieve this without resorting to vba code.

Query1 to select the records you have without a current location. Then an Insert / Append query to insert those records from Query1.

You *could* use a sub query but access gets funny about certain sub-queries in action queries.

Comment: Do you have idea how to write those two queries to make them working because I trying but it didn't want to work ?   :(

Comment: What have you tried for the first query ? Edit your original question and add the query to it, for clarity.